# How to replace an array with new array value in a file

Tags: php

I want to replace an array code inside my php file with new array dynamically

For e.g

```
<?php
  $my_Array = array("key1" => "valu1");
?>
```

to

```
<?php
  $my_Array = array("key2" => "valu2");
?>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: In your file there is `<?php $my_Array .. ?>` or just `return array(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using url parameters like below.

Your url should be like `mywebsite.com/test.php?key1=value1&key2=value2`

In your php file

```
$myarray = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $myarray[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($myarray);
```

Output should be like below

```
Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's saved in file and you need to replace it, use something like this:

```
<?php
  $file = 'filename.php'; // path to the file
  $data = file_get_contents($file);
  $old = array("key1","valu1"); // old values to replace
  $new = array("key2","valu2"); // the new values
  $data = str_replace($old,$new,$data);
  file_put_contents($file,$data);
?>
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Quite close but it's not working properly for eg I have following array <?php $a = array("Leads" => "Leads", "Single_Leads" => "Leads"); then I want to replace it with $a = array("Leads" => "Lead", "Single_Leads" => "Leads");  it is doing $a = array("Leads" => "Lead", "Single_Lead" => "Lead");